# Using server side PHP code from client side C#

Tags: c#, php, client-side

I have a server side PHP script that looks like this

```
class MyObject {
function GetResult($input){
//some code
return $result;
}
}
```

I want to instantiate this object and call the GetResult function from client side c# application and get the get the result. How can i do so?

Comment: You can't do that. Only data can be passed between servers and clients. You'll have to define this function on both your server and client. I think you may need a web service of some kind here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax call to hit on that PHP page and get the results from that PHP page.
Just use JQuery Ajax function like this and make object initialization in PHP page only.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.php",
      data: {someParameter: "some value"},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) 
      {

      }
    });
```